# How to create custom WEEKOFYEAR index in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to custom build a week index (1-52) The logic should be like:

1. Start with the 1st Saturday of January of a year
2. Build custom intervals from every Saturday (start of the week) to Fridays (end of the week) and increment the week index by 1.

> Example:
>   Week 23 will include July 3 2021 - July 9 2021 
> Week 24 will include
> July 10 2021- July 16 2021 etc.

I tried using `Select WEEKOFYEAR(date) from table` but this format will be tied to the general ISO calendar, so it won't match up with my custom week index aggregation. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Probably can be answered with a combination of `dayofweek()`, `dense_rank()` and `mod(x, 7) + 6`

Comment: @drum do you have a sql code concept ?

Comment: I don't have snowflake so can't test it out but it comes down to creating a date dimension that contains a column with your custom week day and referencing it throughout your queries

Comment: Are you sure Jul 3 - Jul 9 is week 23? There are 188 days between Jan 2 and Jul 9 this year. 188 / 7 = ~26.8 so even factoring in a week or two for when the week starts and ends this doesn't seem to line up right.

Comment: Can a week index have less than 7 days? What if 31st December is a Saturday. Will the last week index consist of just 1 day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... I put in the comments that I think according to your week policy the weeks for July will actually be higher:

```
create or replace function MY_WEEK(D date)
returns number(38,0)
language sql
as
$$

floor((D - next_day(date_from_parts(date_part(y, D), 1, 1) - interval '1 day', 'saturday')) / 7 ) + 1

$$;

select MY_WEEK('2021-01-21');
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like this to get the first Saturday of the year:

```
select next_day(date_from_parts(:year, 1, 1) - interval '1 day', 'saturday')
```

Then to get weeks from this date, you can use:

```
select first_saturday + n * interval '1 week' as week_start,
       first_saturday + (n + 1) * interval '1 week' - interval '1 day' as week_end
from (select row_number() over (order by seq4()) as n,
             next_day(date_from_parts(:year, 1, 1) - interval '1 day', 'saturday') as first_saturday
      from table(generator(rowcount => 52))
     ) x
```

Comment: This code does not work for me. it erros at: select next_day(date_from_parts(:year, 1, 1) - interval '1 day', 'saturday') by giving me SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 32 Bind variable :year not set.

Comment: @titu84hh . . . That is for your year.  Put in the value you want.